# primeNG sortable <p-table not loading if user clicked sort first

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a <p-table with sortable columns straight from primeng's own example except it is not loaded with data in ngInit, but on button click and instead of assigning data all at once I add each row in a loop.
See here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-sr8pbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If the first thing you do after the page loads is click the button, it loads the table and shows the data (works as expected), but if you reload the page and click on a sort icon of any column first, and then click the button, data is not shown in the table.

Data is actually loaded into the array assigned to [value] but not rendered.

There is a workaround actually in the comments in the example.
The point of the question is to determine what causes the bug. Is it something in the .push method? something in primeng? or something in angular like the inability to detect that the array has changed when the elements are appended to it? I am leaning towards the last but don't know how to track it down further and also how to explain the difference in behavior - when clicking sort first.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the behavior you're experiencing depends on both the JavaScript `push` method and the `@Input` property mechanism in Angular.

Firstly, regarding the `push` method in JavaScript:

The outcome of using the `push` method depends on the type of data you're pushing into an array. When you push objects or arrays, JavaScript adds a reference to the original object or array. However, for primitive types like numbers or booleans, JavaScript pushes a copy of the value. This distinction is crucial as it affects how changes to the pushed elements reflect in the original array. To dive deeper into this topic, you can explore this article: [Is JavaScript Array.push() a Deep or Shallow Copy?](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/array-push-in-javascript-is-it-deep-or-shallow-copy-90cd195ec5b7#:%7E:text=By%20now%20you%20might%20have,will%20modify%20the%20same%20reference.).

Secondly, concerning the `@Input` property in Angular:

In Angular, the `@Input` property detects changes when the reference of the data it's bound to changes. When you use the spread operator or any other method that creates a new array or object, it does change the reference of the data. Therefore, Angular's change detection mechanism should detect these changes, and the component should be notified when the products change.

> In summary, the behavior you're observing is a combination of how
> JavaScript handles `push` and how Angular's `@Input` property works.

---

## Clarification:

There is no bug but, when perform sort on the PrimeNG table component under the hood you will find this part of code  inside the function called `sortSingle()` which is responsible to do sort on table:
[sortSingle function in Table component](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/125fcbe27a8a4b361a3bd3feb5d0389f3ef56385/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L1514C5-L1514C15)

```
 else {
                    this.value.sort((data1, data2) => {
                        let value1 = ObjectUtils.resolveFieldData(data1, field);
                        let value2 = ObjectUtils.resolveFieldData(data2, field);
                        let result = null;

                        if (value1 == null && value2 != null) result = -1;
                        else if (value1 != null && value2 == null) result = 1;
                        else if (value1 == null && value2 == null) result = 0;
                        else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string') result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
                        else result = value1 < value2 ? -1 : value1 > value2 ? 1 : 0;

                        return order * result;
                    });

                    this._value = [...this.value]; // this line
                }
```

The last line of this code is just update the reference of the value in order to detect the changes.

**In your component:**

When you click the button to retrieve the data after that and use push method the value property doesn't change because you don't change the reference of the value but when using spread operator it works with you.

***For more clarification:
I will use a custom sort.***

hopefully we can do a custom sort on the table like so:

```
  customSort(event: SortEvent) {
    event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
      let value1 = data1[event.field];
      let value2 = data2[event.field];
      let result = null;

      if (value1 == null && value2 != null) result = -1;
      else if (value1 != null && value2 == null) result = 1;
      else if (value1 == null && value2 == null) result = 0;
      else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string')
        result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
      else result = value1 < value2 ? -1 : value1 > value2 ? 1 : 0;

      return event.order * result;
    });

    // this.pTable.value = [...event.data]; // if you uncomment this code the problem will back because of the same reason explained above
  }
```

in html:

```
  <p-table [value]="products1" #pTable (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true">
```

Comment: I don't see how this fine distinction about value types vs reference types being elements of the array is in any way relevant to the question. As for your explanation that it works when the array reference changes. Dah!  Did you read the last paragraph of my question? Please do.

Comment: I have reviewed the final paragraph of your question and would like to provide a clearer explanation of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I always try my answers on `stackblitz` and I'm sure it works. Please, just make sure to add `[customSort]="true"`. This is the `stackblitz` link https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-b1erco?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
I apologize sincerely; I'm genuinely trying to help you.

Comment: My apologies, adding [customSort]="true" (which I missed) did make it work. It is an interesting observation and does explain why it works differently after sort. The total picture is not yet complete, but it's a good find and is certainly part of the picture.

Comment: I'm delighted to contribute, even if it's just a part of the solution.